# how to translate facebook's like button into another language only with javascript?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have a page where the english version facebook's like button is loaded by default. I can only manipulate the page with javascript and don't have access to certain things, i.e. facebook script. So, how can I have that like button translated into another language, say spanish? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "Like" button? `$('.like_link .default_message').html('Something Else')`?

Comment: yes, but the button resides inside an iframe and I cannot change it this way.

Comment: I am missing where the iFrame is.  My facebook doesn't have an iFrame.  Are you using GreaseMonkey?

Comment: no I am not. the facebook xfbml script that you include to your site creates that iframe automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's going to be extremely difficult - there isn't a 'nice' way to do it. This is because the like button lives inside an iframe, and you can't access the contents of it from within your page, with javascript or anything else.

You can manipulate the iframe's `src` attribute - check the facebook documentation to see if you can pass in a language parameter - something like: `&lang=es` on the end of the URL.

**Updated** - the URL parameter is *locale*, as in: &locale=es_ES

Comment: thanks, but the thing is the facebook script is loaded automatically and I cannot control that.

Comment: No, but once it's loaded, you can examine the like button iframe, and change its src attribute. Changing this would cause it to reload with the new value. If you can find a new value which sets the language at the facebook end, you should be in business.

Answer (score 7):

The source of the facebook connect javascript is: http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js

just change en_US to the locale you want. en_ES is Spain's locale, and a list of all facebook locales is at http://facebook.com/translations/FacebookLocales.xml

Comment: +1 Spain's locale is es_ES. Here is a full list of Facebook locales: http://www.facebook.com/translations/FacebookLocales.xml Perhaps you can add the to your answer, if you think it is a good addition.

Comment: thanks, but the thing is the facebook script is loaded automatically and I cannot control that.

Comment: @Bahodir if you cannot change the script where it is loaded you can change the url with javascript after it is loaded.

Comment: @Craig, thanks for your reply. I just don't see how changing the js url would change the facebook like button's text into spanish, when the button is already loaded.

Comment: Changing the src URL on the iframe will cause it to reload with the new URL. In fact, I just tested this, and it works. Add '&locale=es_ES' to the end of the src parameter, and the button loads in Spanish.

Comment: Thanks, I thought you said to change the script url, not the iframe url. My bad. I wish I could mark your answer the best answer, but beejamin's answer is correct too and I already marked his answer. Hope you are not offended. ;)

Comment: @Bahodir You cannot change the js url after it has loaded, but you can change the iframe url, as Beejamin described

Comment: One thing I noticed, is that not all like buttons have the locale in the path name - when the format starts with: http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php? - in this case, adding the &locale= param will work.

Answer (score 0):

Others are talking about an iFrame, which I don't see anywhere on my Facebook page.  If you can use GreaseMonkey, or are able to access the links via JS, you can use the following:

1. jQuery:

   ```
   $('.liketext').html('Something Else')
   ```
2. JavaScript:

   ```
   function getElementsByClass(_class,_obj,_tag) {
      var found = new Array();
      if ( _obj == null )  _obj = document;
      if ( _tag == null )  _tag = '*';

      var els     = _obj.getElementsByTagName(_tag);
      var pattern = new RegExp("(^|\\s)"+_class+"(\\s|$)");

      for (var n=els.length, j = 0; n--; ) {
         if ( pattern.test(els[n].className) ) {
            found[j] = els[n];
            j++;
         }
      }
      return found;
   }

   var likes = getElementsByClass('liketext',document);
   for (var n=likes.length; n--; )
      likes[n].innerHTML = "NEW LIKE TEXT";
   ```

---

#### To target your iFrame:

- ```
  document.getElementById('<your iFrame ID').contentWindow.document;
  ```
- ```
  window.frames[0]
  ```

Example:

- ```
  var iF = document.getElementById('<your iFrame ID>').contentWindow.document;
  // var iF = window.frames[0].document;  // alternative to above

  var likes = getElementsByClass('liketext',iF);
  for (var n=likes.length; n--; )
     likes[n].innerHTML = "NEW LIKE TEXT";
  ```

Comment: sorry if I wasn't clear enough. It's not the facebook page I'm talking about. I'm talking about the like button that you can include in your site.

Comment: thanks for the update, but you are not allowed to access the contents of the iframe because of the same origin policy

Comment: yeah, it sucks in this case, but it's a good thing to have that policy. ;)

Comment: do you have a fiddle we can test out?  with the example above, I'm able to do it from w/in firebug, which I would have thought would suffer from the [origin policy problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: you can set the iframe url to some other domain and you'll see the error. what's a fiddle?